# TypeScript+NextJS destructuring

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

I have object from postgresql:

[image]

Need to get id, name and content on NextJS component like that:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const data = await prisma.note.findFirst()
  return {
    props: {
      userNote: data,
    },
  }
}
interface INote {
  id: number
  name: string
  content: string
}

const Home = ({ name, content, id }: INote) => {
  console.log(name)
  return <div>hello world</div>
}
```

but i got undefined. What's wrong?

Comment: How you're rendering this `Home` component?

Comment: "Home" is main component in pages/index.tsx

Comment: I can get this object if = (userNote: any) => { ... } 
but it's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your props in the Home component are not

```
{
  id: number
  name: string
  content: string
}
```

but actually,

```
{
 userNote: {
  id: number
  name: string
  content: string
 }
}
```

You'll either need to change your destructuring and the type:

```
const Home = ({ userNote: { name, content, id } }: { userNote: INote }) => {
```

or you could change your getServerSideProps:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const data = await prisma.note.findFirst()
  return {
    props: data,
  }
}
```

---

In my experience it's more idiomatic to go with the first approach and change it to:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const data = { id: 1, name: 'test', content: 'content' }
  return {
    props: {
      userNote: data,
    },
  }
}

interface INote {
  id: number
  name: string
  content: string
}

interface HomeProps {
   userNote: INote
}

const Home = ({ userNote: { name, content, id } }: HomeProps) => {
  console.log(name)
  return <div>hello world</div>
}

export default Home
```

Comment: thank you, it works now!